# Hadith explanation and authentication

Tags: hadith, authenticity

There is this hadith said to be quoted in Al suyooti as sagheer that goes "All things not from the remembrance of Allah are futile (lahw) and play " Is this hadith authentic and can someone explain this hadith as well.

Comment: I guess you are referring to "كل شيءٍ ليس من ذِكْر الله فهو لهو"

Comment: I dont know arabic but I think thats the one